# Highcharts angular map chart with tiledwebmap and choropleth not working?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular14, angular-highcharts

I am trying to create a Highcharts choropleth mapchart with the Esri Tiled Web Map(background) in angular 14. both series working if loaded seperately, but if i render a map with both choropleth mapchart series and Esri Tiled Web Map series then pages getting frozen/not working.

working stackblitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-map-tile

Please help me to find solution.

[Expected Map Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oopeM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed the tiledwebmap module in your example.

```
import TiledWebMap from 'highcharts/modules/tiledwebmap';
TiledWebMap(Highcharts);
```

Apart from that, use TopoJSON instead GeoJSON map together with TWM series.

```
import worldMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.topo.json';
```

**Working demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-map-tile-22m1jr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. working now